# I can't make JQueryUI work with ASP.net server controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm sorry i can't find any answer for this.

Is this a known problem? Does it have a solution?

Please help. I'd like to use JQueryUI in ASP.net Server Controls

> sample script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#txtSearch').datepicker({
               showPeriod: true,
               showLeadingZero: true
           });
           $('#Text1').datepicker({
               showPeriod: true,
               showLeadingZero: true
           });
       });
```

> sample markup

```
    <input id="Text1" type="text"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="196px">
    </asp:TextBox>
```

the thing is its working on a regular html control but not on the asp control
i appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below. If you 'view source' of the page, you will see that the ID of the asp.net control has been dynamically changed. Using the below you can access the dynamically generated ID for the txtSearch html element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').timepicker({
               showPeriod: true,
               showLeadingZero: true
           });
           $('#Text1').timepicker({
               showPeriod: true,
               showLeadingZero: true
           });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

when a server control is rendered, the ID of the control is changed. So your txtSearch id would become something like ct001_txtSearch. 
This is the reason that jquery cannot find it because it is looking for id 'txtSearch' but there is no control with id 'txtSearch'.

Try using the clientID to reference the id.

Answer (score 0):

Is the control used with a MasterPage?

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/11/26/finding-controls-in-a-master-page-with-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A quick one could be: just use the html control and mark it as **runat="server"**

Es :

```
<input type="text" id="Textbox1" runat="server">
```

Comment: Use a tool like firebug (or simply view the source of the html page) and find out what is the id produced by asp.net for that control. Or just add a css class to your control and bind the jquery calendar to the class instead of the id.